# Swagger - Comma Separated Parameter List

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using swagger (nswag) in my ASP.NET CORE API project. I have situations which I would like my api call to be something like `/api/users/{userIds}` aka `/api/users/1,2,3` that returns a list of users with the ids 1, 2, or 3.

What I'm finding is that when I make the request using swagger, the Request URL is `/api/users/1%2C2%2C3` and if I make the request `/api/users/1,2,3` (not using swagger), the endpoint cannot be found.

How do I change my configurations to be able to use a comma separated parameter?

Comment: This should be possible if `usersIds` is defined as an `in: path` parameter with `collectionFormat: csv`. Could you post your Swagger YAML/JSON file, and/or your source code for that endpoint?

Comment: My controller method calls look like this, is this what you mean?
`[HttpGet("{UserIds}")]
public IActionResult GetUsers(IEnumerable<int> UserIds)`